# running python module from django shell (manage.py)

Tags: python, database, django, api

I'm try to populate data into my db and I'd like to use the django API to do so. I've written a python module that allows me to this very easily.

However, within the django shell (manage.py), it doesn't seem possible to run my "populate.py" file.

**Is it possible to run my populate.py from the django shell? Or alternatively, should I instead be running a regular python terminal and importing the necessary django components? Either way, I would greatly appreciate some pointers.**

Comment: did you try importing populate from within the django shell? import populate; populate.main() or something like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my standard wrapper for running django stuff from the command line. This is also useful if you have cron scripts you want to run.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, sys
# If this script lives in a child directory of the main project directory
# uncomment the following 2 lines:
#dir_parent = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
#sys.path.insert(0, dir_parent)

from django.core.management import setup_environ
import settings
setup_environ(settings)

from django.db import transaction

# import whatever you like from app.models or whatever
# do random stuff.

# If you are *changing* database records,
# wrap your database code either in:
@transaction.commit_manually
def foo():
   ... stuff
   transaction.commit()

# OR end you script with:
transaction.commit_unless_managed()
```

**Update for comment:**

The variable mentioned above is not `file`, it is `__file__` (i.e. 2 underscores `file` and 2 more underscores). This is always set by the Python interpreter to the full path of the file it occurs in. As the comment says, if this script lives in a child directory of the main directory, the directory-of-the-directory of the filename gives you the directory name of the main project directory, and adding that to `sys.path` will make sure that all of your imports work correctly. If the script lives *in* the main directory and you execute it from there, then you don't need to do that.

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm now getting "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined"

Comment: Thanks! I just had some syntax issues there. Works now. However, I've still decided to wrap as a custom django-admin command to avoid the need for this sort of thing in the future.

Answer (score 4):

You can also consider using the [loaddata command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture) or [create your own command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/)

Answer (score 1):

Try django-extensions it has a runscript command you put in a scripts directory.

Oddly the command seems to be missing from the main documentation but if you google django-extensions runscript you will find examples and documentation.